# backbone router as /en/#xyz and not /#en/xyz

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, pushstate

I'm trying to do something pretty simple.

Here's the scenario:
I have a whole site working great with pushstate enabled browsers. The site works off the basis that the language is the "actual page" for instance:

```
/en/whatever/etc  = index.en.php with  with english headers and encoding & tweaks
/ar/whatever/etc  = index.ar.php with  with arabic headers and encoding & tweaks
/ru/whatever/etc  = index.ru.php with  with russian headers and encoding & tweaks
```

It's really slick and works nicely with pushstate as I mentioned. The problem is when I try to use the same router code with the hash alternative.

Backbone's router seems to want to do this:

```
/#/en/whatever/etc = bad because it's not based correctly
/#/ar/whatever/etc = and so on
```

what I want it to do is:

```
/en/#whatever/etc
/ar/#whatever/etc
/ru/#whatever/etc
..and so on

or even:

/en/#/whatever/etc
/ar/#/whatever/etc
/ru/#/whatever/etc
..and so on
```

But i can't find a way without tweaking backbones source to implement this. I'm kind of against changing backbone.js unless I really have to because of the futureproofing factor.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `root` option in the [Backbone `History` object:](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#History)

Quote the docs:

> If your application is not being served from the root url / of your domain, be sure to tell History where the root really is, as an option: `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: "/public/search/"})`

You're going to have to do some code that happens on your landing page that looks at what language they're using, and then sends them to `/[LANG CODE]/`.  Then on your server, you just map requests for `/[LANG CODE]/` to your .html file.

In your HTML file look at the `location.pathname` variable, strip off the first `/[LANG CODE]/` part and use that as your `root` value for the options hash.

```
var lang = "/"+_.first(location.pathname.split('/')+"/";
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: lang}); // if you're using pushState, otherwise omit or set to false
```

This will cause your URLs to be:

```
/en/#whatever/etc
/ru/#whatever/etc
```

Comment: hey thanks again for saving me tkone! I'm going to have to start sending you banknotes instead of points soon ;-)

Comment: @Alex haha not a problem.  Glad to be of service!